# Bubbling Newest Version of Git Submodule

Tags: git, shell

**Introduction**

Hi there,

I am working with submodules, in a particular project I am working on I have submodules that are nested to 3 layers or more.

Sometimes I will make a minor change in the deepest nested submodule and I want that change to be on all parent submodules that use it as a dependency.

As of right now when I make such a change I commit the change in the deepest nested submodule, then `cd ..` until I'm in a parent directory that has it as a submodule and then I use `git add submodule_name && git commit -m "update submodule version" && git push"` in each one as I bubble up the directories until each of the parent submodules have update their dependency.

**concretely**

If I have git repositories `A, B, C`, where `C` is added as a submodule of `B` and then `B` is added as a submodule of `A` with the directory structure `A/B/C`, when I make a minor change to `C` I commit and push that change, go back to `B`, then use `git add C && git commit -m "update version of C" && git push"`, then go back to `A` and use `git add B && git commit -m "update version of B" && git push"`.

I am wondering if there there is a command either built into git itself or a small script I can run that would simplify this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# after you've committed in your submodule:
( this=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
  while up=$(git -C "$this"/.. rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&-)
  do
        cd "$this"/..
        git add ${this##*/}
        git commit -m "updating ${this#$up/}"
        this=$up
  done
)
```

will do all the adding and committing